# WPF DataGrid SelectionChanged event cancelation cell focus issue

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am performing the check inside the datagrid selection changed event. 
If my condition is satisfied the code should get executed and the selected item should be highlighted (or gets focus), if the condition is not satisfied the control should return and
the previously selected item should remain selected.

What's happening here is if condition is not met the selected item is not changing (which is working as desired) but the focus still gets shifted to the cell selected now, so the cell selected item is the previous cell while the one in focus is the cell that fired the event.

I've tried datagrid.dispatcher.invoke approach but that doesn't seem to be working.
Also I've tried to set the datagrid.selectedindex=e.removeditem[0] which leads the control again into selection changed event thus by putting into a continuous loop.

Please suggest something.

**EDIT**:

```
dataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) 
{ 
   if (!IsDirty) 
   { 
       if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0) 
       { 
          SelectedProfile = e.AddedItems[0] as profile; 
       } 
       if (e.RemovedItems.Count > 0) 
       { 
       } 
   }
   else 
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Save the profile selected", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning); 
      return; 
   } 
}
```

Comment: What's the condition you're basing this off of, and how are you cancelling the selection? It's possible you could get away with a `DataTrigger` that sets `IsReadOnly` on the `DataGridRow` or `DataGridCell` instead

Comment: The flag gets its value in some other function and whether the flag is set or not we want the datagrid cell to change, i 've restricted the cell change but not able to restrict the focus , which in any case will shift to the new cell clicked. Unregistering the selectionchanged event is not working either

Comment: Used DataGrid.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() in the selection changed event the previous cell is highlighted as desired but the cell clicked becomes editable

Answer (score 2):

Prevent the loop.

```
void OnSelectionChanged(Object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // condition code
    if (conditionFailed)
    {
        datagrid.SelectionChanged -= OnSelectionChanged;
        datagrid.Selectedindex = e.Removeditem[0];
        datagrid.SelectionChanged += OnSelectionChanged;
    }
}
```

Comment: Registering or Unregistering the OnSelectionChanged() do nothing.
Even if you unregister the datagridSelectionchanged event it will no doubt won't take the control to the OnSelectionChanged(Object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
but it will still the change the focus on the cell clicked , the problem is how to restrict change in focus

Comment: @HemantBhatt: you mentioned "I've tried to set the datagrid.selectedindex=e.removeditem[0] which leads the control again into selection changed event thus by putting into a continuous loop".  This seems to imply that the problem with this approach is _continuous loop_.  Unregistering, selecting, registering would seem to circumvent _continuous loop_ issue.

Comment: here is my code
private void dataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsDirty)
            {
                if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
                {
                    SelectedProfile = e.AddedItems[0] as profile;
                }
                if (e.RemovedItems.Count > 0)
                {
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Save the profile selected", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
                return;
            }
        }

Comment: if the user has changed some thing  in the selected profile and isDirty flag is set to true i want the message box to display "save the profile selected" which it is doing and the datagrid focus should remain at the profile selected earlier not to the cell which cause this event to fire

Comment: Used DataGrid.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() in the selection changed event the previous cell is highlighted as desired but the cell clicked becomes editable

Comment: @HemantBhatt `DataGrid.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` will start an asynchronous operation, so the cell is probably getting selected in the click event, while whatever you are doing in the `BeginInvoke()` call is simply changing the highlighted item after the selection has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem.

What need to be done was to enable the dirty flag at `textbox_PreviewKeyDown()` event
and then performing the dirty check at `datagrid_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown()` event.

If dirty is found set then setting `e.handled=true` so that control skips code execution for this flow.